# How to get files using their modified date and time from Laravel amazon s3 bucket

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-storage

We are using an amazon s3 bucket for storing files. There are very large number of files present, so we need to read files using date and time filter on which all the files have been created.

We are using Laravel storage library for accessing files.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
$disk = Storage::disk('<disk>');
$files = $disk->files('<folder>');
```

currently, the process is getting killed due to large amount of files.so we need to filter the files using date and time. Is there any way to read files using date and time?

Comment: You are not providing enough info. Either your files need to have a date in their name, or you need to maintain a table containing metadata about the files/dates/extentions/sizes/etc.

Answer (score 1):

`listContents()` will be useful, in the example below I am getting all files in a folder, excluding folders using filter() and creating an array which is keyed by the last modified timestamp.

```php
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
foreach ($disk->listContents('some/directory')->filter(fn ($value) => $value->isFile())->getIterator() as $file) {
    $files[$file->lastModified()] = $file->path();
}
```

In my particular scenario I was wanting to limit to 10 files and delete the old ones, so I did:

```php
krsort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);
$disk->delete(array_slice($files, 10));
```

[This answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-schedule-to-remove-files-older-than?reply=608888) on Laracasts was also very helpful.